# Request permissions based on API level

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), we can ask permissions at run time. However, according to the docs, all permissions still need to be defined in AndroidManifest.xml so in APIs lower than 23, these permissions will be granted prior to installing the app.

I want to request `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission only at runtime - since this is a sensitive permission, requesting it prior to installation without any context will cause a decrease in downloads.

I am targeting my app to API levels 11+, so I wonder whether it is possible not to ask for the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in older APIs (i.e. not list it in AndroidManifest for APIs older than 23), and only request it for APIs 23+.

**Update**

For clarification, I want to know whether it is possible to do the following:

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
IF API_LEVEL>=23: {
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
}
ELSE:
{
}
```

Comment: At runtime you put the permission check by the version if version>=23 than    check the runtime permission in else do nothing.......

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini, don't I have to list this permissions statically in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: "On all versions of Android, your app needs to declare both the normal and the dangerous permissions it needs in its app manifest, as described in Declaring Permissions. "

Comment: If you are trying to using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need to request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it includes permission for both providers.

Comment: Simple and straight answer : **No**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You *can't* request a Permission which is not declared in **Manifest**.
- You *can't* change your **Manifest** at runtime.

What you can do is to make **1 flavor targeting API 23+** with permission declared and **another flavor without the permission targeting API 23-**.

Answer (score 16):

I think you can do this using:

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="string" android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

You can read more about it in the official documentation: [uses-permission-sdk-23](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element.html)

Comment: Glad it help you. Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

no that's not possible in **AndroidManifest.xml**

you can ask the permission before using the functions based on the that permission.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) 
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           //Ask for permission
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                requestCode); 

}else{

//already permitted . Do your work here..
}
```

now override onRequestPermissionsResult() Method to see if user permitted the request or not

```
@Override 
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission is granted, Now you can execute function 

            } else { 

                // permission denied, Don't execute your function to avoid any crashes

            } 
            return; 

}
```

you don't have to check for SDK version here
for more information [click here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
Happy Coding :)