# Camera permission below API 23 only

Tags: android, permissions, camera, android-6.0-marshmallow, flashlight

I've made an simple flash application which toggles the flashlight. Everything works fine, but I'm having a few issues with the permission on API higher than 23.

In API 23 a new method was added for handling the flashlight mode. More precisely `CameraManager.setTorchMode(String cameraId, boolean enabled)`. 
This new method does not require to open the camera anymore just for handling the flashlight actions.

My problem is that below API 23, this method does not exist thus I need to access the camera, this forcing me to use the camera permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>` in Manifest.

But I want to avoid requesting the camera permission on API higher than 23 as this won't affect the functionality of the application.

Does anyone know how I can request the camera permission only on APIs below 23?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request permissions based on API level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157814/request-permissions-based-on-api-level)

Comment: It is impossible. Unless you create a new apk that works only for API 23+.

Comment: @TOP, i was thinking about that, but this could be too much just for a permission check. I will consider this only as a last resolve.

Comment: @GSerg I do not think it is the same scenario. I've read that one and for that one the fix could be done with: `<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="string" android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />`. I want to do the opposite.

Comment: Found the solution. Posted an answer for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution for this. It seems the `uses-permission` allows for some customization and I found `android:maxSdkVersion` property to do just what I want.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>`

I hope this helps others in a similar situation.

More on this can be found in the official documentation: [uses-permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

Comment: shouldn't it be `android:maxSdkVersion="22"` ? 
As from 23 we've `CameraManager.setTorchMode` API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this permission in the manifest file:
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />`